# Increasing / decrasing chance on random module

Tags: python, random, probability

For example I am programming a game . I need some money . Chests is free but keys is paid . How can I increase the chance of ***key needed premium chest*** and how can I decrase the chance of ***fully free premium chest***

```
import random 

list1 = ["fully free premium chest", "key needed premium chest", "fully free normal chest"]


random.choice(list1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) and give weights to your different options, proportional to the probability you want to give to each of them.

> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with
>   replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.
>
> If a weights sequence is specified, selections are made according to
>   the relative weights. Alternatively, if a cum_weights sequence is
>   given, the selections are made according to the cumulative weights
>   (perhaps computed using itertools.accumulate()). For example, the
>   relative weights [10, 5, 30, 5] are equivalent to the cumulative
>   weights [10, 15, 45, 50]. Internally, the relative weights are
>   converted to cumulative weights before making selections, so supplying
>   the cumulative weights saves work.

For example, you could use the weights [10, 40, 2] to give the second item a larger probability to be chosen, and a small one for the last item.

It would be:

```
import random 

list1 = ["fully free premium chest", "key needed premium chest", "fully free normal chest"]


random.choices(list1, weights=[10, 40, 2], k=1)[0]
# 'key needed premium chest'
```